# Is the time complexity of this function O(log n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to do [this problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/description/), and the following is the solution I came up with:

```js
var findKthLargest = function(nums, k) {
  //var tmp = nums.slice();
  var iteration = 0;

  while (iteration < k) {
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      var cut;
      if (nums[i] > max) {
        max = nums[i];
        cut = i;
      }
    }
    nums.splice(cut, 1);
    iteration++;
  }

  return max;
};
```

Now, I believe this is a *log n* solution because what I’m basically doing is removing the largest value in the array, which decreases my number of comparisons. However, it only beats 59% of the JavaScript solutions, which makes me think I might not have the right complexity.

Comment: The `.splice()` operation is linear (O(n)). And for other reasons this is definitely not O(log(n)).

Comment: AHHHHHHHHH, thank you. So it would be O(nlogn)

Comment: Which part of it do you think is `O(log(n))`? The `for` loop is `O(n)` as well.

Comment: The whole thing is `O(k * n * n)`

Comment: Well the array is getting shorter every iteration, and we're calling splice on each iteration so wouldn't it be o(log(n))?

Comment: The array is only shrinking linearly each iteration. It's actually `O(n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... * (n-k+1))`

Comment: so it's actually just o(n!)?

Comment: Sorry, I made a bunch of mistakes above. I've gone through the full logic in my answer.

Comment: Those should actually have been `O(n + (n-1) + (n-2)...)`

Comment: that splice() is expensive. otoh, you can't really calc such complexity realistically in js because of optimizations like tracing and prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `k` iterations of the `while()` loop (which, I think, would be more idiomatically written as `for(var j = 0; j < k; j++)`).

The first iteration then performs `n` iterations of the `for` loop, and `nums.splice(cut, 1)` is `O(n)` because it has to shift all the array elements from `cut` to `n`. `O(2n)` is the same as `O(n)` because constant factors are ignored in big-O calculation.

The second iteration performs `n-1` iterations. This is also `O(n)` because we ignore constant adjustments in big-O notation. The same goes for the `splice`.

So the final result is that it's `O(k * n)`, since you have `k` iterations of the outer loop, and the inner loops are each `O(n)`. The worst case, when `k >= n`, is `O(n^2)`